How can i generate the Flex&Bison target by CMake?
i was writing a sql parser, i use cmake configure my project.
source code directories are as follows:
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt          // root CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt      // src  CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.c
    └── parser
        ├── CMakeLists.txt  // parser CMakeLists.txt
        ├── parse.y
        └── scan.l

i run cmake .. in build dir, it works without error, but error occured after make (in build dir), error msg (no flex&bison output in build/src/parser):
[ 50%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/demo.dir/entry.c.o
/home/.../MyDB/src/main.c:1:10: fatal error: parse.tab.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "parse.tab.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:76: src/CMakeFiles/demo.dir/entry.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:115: src/CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

main.c (i didn't write a lot of code because I wanted to test the build first):
#include "parse.tab.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}

root CMakeLists.txt content:
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.22.1 )
project( MyDB )
add_subdirectory( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src )

src CMakeLists.txt content:
add_subdirectory( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/parser )

include_directories( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser )

add_executable( demo
        entry.c
        ${BISON_RawParser_OUTPUTS}
        ${FLEX_RawScanner_OUTPUTS} )

target_include_directories( demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser )

parser CMakeLists.txt (refs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindFLEX.html)
find_package(BISON REQUIRED)
find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)

bison_target( RawParser
    parse.y
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parse.tab.c
    DEFINES_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parse.tab.h )

flex_target( RawScanner
    scan.l
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/scan.yy.c )

add_flex_bison_dependency( RawScanner RawParser )

please give me some tips, thanks!
If additional details are needed I will be happy to provide them
I have tried writing the contents of parser CMakeLists.txt to src CMakeLists.txt. This writing method seems to be fine, but the current writing method does not seem to trigger bison&flex to generate their targets. I do not know why it has to be like this. I'm confused.
I want flex&bison's targets to be generated in subdirectories (build/src/parser), which would be more elegant (to me).

Variables BISON_RawParser_OUTPUTS is defined by bison_target call in src/parser/CMakeLists.txt. This variable is local to that script and not visible in the src/CMakeLists.txt. The same is about FLEX_RawScanner_OUTPUTS variable. You need either to move your scanner/parser logic into src/CMakeLists.txt, or leave it in src/parser/CMakeLists.txt but propagate the variables in that script to the caller (by using PARENT_SCOPE option of set command).

i append set(BISON_OUTPUTS ${BISON_RawParser_OUTPUTS} PARENT_SCOPE) to src/parser/CMakeLists.txt (Flex as well), and used it in src/CMakeLists.txt, but it doesn't work. compilation error is exactly the same as before.

Oh, my bad: bison_target and flex_target create files via add_custom_command mechanism. Those files could only by consumed in the same CMakeLists.txt. So you have no other choice than moving content of src/parser/CMakeLists.txt into src/CMakeLists.txt.

try to search where parse.tab.h is located with find command. I think you need just change target_include_directories( demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser ) to target_include_directories( demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
